# MVC3 DbExtensions.Include Method Null Values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have these 2 database tables that are modeled like this:

```
CalloutToProduct 
----------------- 
| id 
| CalloutID 
| CalloutTypeID 
| ProductIdentifier 
| DateStart 
| DateEnd 
| IsActive 
-----------------

CalloutTypeValue
-----------------
| id
| CalloutTypeID
| Value
| Comment
-----------------
```

(As an aside, the database seems to be very poorly modeled and these tables as is with most, if not all of the database, are/is NOT normalized, nor are there proper relationships with proper PK's or FK's set up on these tables, so all things being equal, I think the relationship is 1-to-1.

Being new to MVC, I'm not sure if this is part of my problem...)

Continuing, I've also created these 2 class models in a code-first fashion :

```
public class CalloutToProduct
{
[Key, ForeignKey("CalloutTypeValues")]
public int id { get; set; }
public int CalloutID { get; set; }
public int? CalloutTypeID { get; set; }
public string ProductIdentifier { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; }
public int? IsActive { get; set; }
public virtual CalloutTypeValue CalloutTypeValues { get; set; }
}

public class CalloutTypeValue
{
[Key, ForeignKey("CalloutToProduct")]
public int id { get; set; }
public int? CalloutTypeID { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
public string Comment { get; set; }
public virtual CalloutToProduct CalloutToProduct { get; set; }
}
And a context model:

public class CalloutToProduct
public class CalloutContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<CalloutToProduct> CalloutToProduct { get; set; }
public DbSet<CalloutTypeValue> CalloutTypeValue { get; set; }
public DbSet<CalloutValue> CalloutValue { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

}
}
```

I also have a controller using the DbExtensions.Include Method set up like this:

```
public ViewResult Index(int page = 1)
{
var callouts = db.CalloutToProduct.Include(c => c.CalloutTypeValues);
return View(callouts
.OrderBy(p => p.DateStart)
.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
.Take(PageSize));
}
```

And a view that looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MarketingWebsiteTools.Models.CalloutToProduct>


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>
CalloutID
</th>
<th>
CalloutTypeID
</th>
<th>
ProductIdentifier
</th>
<th>
@Html.ActionLink("Date Start", "Index", new { SortOrder=ViewBag.NameSortParm })
</th>
<th>
DateEnd
</th>
<th>
IsActive
</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>Comments</th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalloutID)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalloutTypeID)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductIdentifier)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateStart)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateEnd)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalloutTypeValues.Value)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalloutTypeValues.Comment)
</td>

<td>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
</td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

My problem is that the item.CalloutTypeValues object is NULL, so Value and Comment aren't being populated in my View.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've Googled a bit and it's mentioned that I need to explicity load these entities using the virtual keyword, however I believe that's what I've done in the Entity classes.

Addition:

I altered the Controller using LINQ to SQL like this:

```
public ViewResult Index(int page = 1){
    var callouts = from c in db.CalloutToProduct
    join ctv in db.CalloutTypeValue on c.CalloutTypeID equals ctv.CalloutTypeID
    select new
    {
    c.id,
    c.CalloutID,
    c.CalloutTypeID,
    c.ProductIdentifier,
    c.DateStart,
    c.DateEnd,
    c.IsActive,
    ctv.Value,
    ctv.Comment
    };
    return View(callouts
    .OrderBy(p => p.DateStart)
    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
    .Take(PageSize));
}
```

But I have the incorrect model in my view, so I receive this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`9[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.String]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MarketingWebsiteTools.Models.CalloutToProduct]'.

Thanks in advance.

Doug

Comment: If there are no PK's in the database, you'll need to use Join's in your LINQ - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085

Comment: did my answer and our chat help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your View has

```
@model IEnumerable<MarketingWebsiteTools.Models.CalloutToProduct>
```

and you're passing an anonymous type to it. Try creating a ViewModel called `CalloutToProductViewModel` and map your query items to the ViewModel

*side note: keep your controller lean and put your business in a service.*

---

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MarketingWebsiteTools.Models.CalloutToProductViewModel>
```

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult Index(int page = 1){

    var model = CalloutService.GetCallouts(page);
    return View(model);

}
```

**Service**

```
public class CalloutService
{
    public CalloutToProductViewModel GetCallouts(int page)
    {
        var callouts = from c in db.CalloutToProduct
        join ctv in db.CalloutTypeValue on c.CalloutTypeID equals ctv.CalloutTypeID
        select new
        {
        c.id,
        c.CalloutID,
        c.CalloutTypeID,
        c.ProductIdentifier,
        c.DateStart,
        c.DateEnd,
        c.IsActive,
        ctv.Value,
        ctv.Comment
        };

        // ******
        var calloutVM = // map the anonymous type to a POCO View Model and do your orders
        // ******

        // .OrderBy(p => p.DateStart)
        // .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
        // .Take(PageSize));

        return (calloutsVM)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chase.  One more question:  In which directory does the service live?

Comment: I often build out a "Services" directory inside my business project. I often call my business project "Core", so that the namespacing would be `MyApplication.Core.Services.CalloutService.GetCallouts`, or something along those lines. In medium to large applications, it's often good to have a separate project for business stuff, in smaller projects, it can live in a "Services" directory within the root of the application.

Comment: It did take a bit for me to learn. A view model is just a POCO that you can pass between your View and your Controller. The POCO is simply a class populated with properties.

Comment: Taking a [look around SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=viewmodel&submit=search) is a great place to start learning.

Comment: Did the above example work for you? Even if you don't use a service layer, the principles of sending a model to the view instead of an anonymous type should solve your issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9331/discussion-between-doug-and-chase-florell)